# how can I use datalist in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a code below:

```
 <input list="browsers">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Google Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

I need it in yii2 some like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'browser')->dropdownList() ?>
```

Can one help me..

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question. You can put any html into view file you just need to make sure it's not inside of `<?php ?>` marks.

Answer (score 1):

Using datalist only means that you need to reference it in the input element.

If you are using `ActiveForm` widget you can do it like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'browser', [
    'inputOptions' => [
        'list' => 'browsers',
        // here we can set any html attributes for input element
    ],
]); ?>

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Google Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

your try that

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'browser')->widget(Select2::classname(),[
      'data' =>
              [
                'Internet Explorer' => 'Internet Explorer',
                'Firefox' => 'Firefox',
                'Google Chrome' =>'Google Chrome',
                'Opera' => 'Opera',
                'Safari' => 'Safari',
                'ZEN' => 'ZEN',

              ],
      'options' =>['placeholder' =>'select some operator...'],
      'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' =>true,
        ]
      ]) ?>
```